# Error 1054 - previous articles did not do it

Tags: sql, join

I'm trying to insert into one table, information from 4 tables.

I'm getting an error 1054 Unknown Column in on Clause. I found previous articles for this error but they do not seem to apply to my situation as i have tried them.

```
create table Medici(
    medic_id int not null primary key auto_increment,
    nume text not null,
    prenume text not null,
    specialitate text not null,
    statut enum('primar','specialist'),
    Nume_complet text AS (concat_ws('_',nume,prenume)),
    unique (Nume_complet(100)));

Create Table Pacienti(
       Pacient_Id int not null primary key auto_increment,
       Nume text Not Null,
       Prenume text Not Null, 
       Nume_complet text AS (concat_ws(' ',nume,prenume)),
       unique (Nume_complet(100)));

Create table Cabinete(
       Denumire_Id Int Not Null Primary Key Auto_increment,
       Denumire varchar(255) not null unique
       );
Create table Vizite(
        Vizite_Id int not null primary key auto_increment,
        Data_si_ora datetime not null,
        IdMedic int not null,
        IdPacient int not null,
        IdDenumire int not null,
        foreign key (IdMedic) references Medici(Medic_id),
        foreign key (IdPacient) references Pacienti(Pacient_Id),
        foreign key (IdDenumire) references Cabinete(Denumire_id));

 Create table Intermediar(
        Intermediar_Id int not null primary key auto_increment,
        DataVizita date not null,
        OraIntrare time,
        NumePacient text not null,
        PrenumePacient text not null,
        NumeMedic text not null,
        PrenumeMedic text not null,
        Cabinet varchar(255) not null
        );

Load Data local infile
     'C:\\medici.txt'
     into table medici
     Fields Terminated by ','
     Lines terminated by '\n'
     Ignore 1 lines
     (nume, prenume,statut,specialitate);

Load Data local infile
     'C:\\vizite.txt'
     into table Intermediar
     Fields Terminated by ','
     Lines terminated by '\n'
     Ignore 1 lines
     (@vardata,OraIntrare,NumePacient,PrenumePacient,NumeMedic,PrenumeMedic,Cabinet)
     set DataVizita = str_to_date(@vardata, '%d/%m/%Y');

Insert into Pacienti (Nume,Prenume) select distinct NumePacient,PrenumePacient
from Intermediar;

Insert into Cabinete(Denumire) select distinct Cabinet from Intermediar;


insert into vizite (Data_si_ora,IdMedic,IdPacient,IdDenumire) select concat_ws(' ',DataVizita, Oraintrare) from Intermediar
inner join Medici on Vizite.IdMedic = Medici.Medic_Id 
inner join Pacienti on Vizite.IdPacient = Pacienti.Pacient_Id
inner join Cabinete on Vizite.IdDenumire = Cabinete.Denumire_Id;
```

I've read previous articles posted here - related to mixing join type and use of commas without parenthesis for the table names. These do not apply.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Help us help you - please share the tables' definitions and the exact text of the error

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.7 with workbench 6.3. Error message is Error 1054 unknown column 'Vizite.Medic_id' in 'on clause'. From the previous articles it was stated that this is due when there are multiple tables from which you select the data and you need to enclose in paranthesis. This is not the case

Comment: It is a syntax error caused by the `SELECT` statement at the end.  If you test the `SELECT` statement, you will see that table `Vizite` is not visible within that `SELECT` statement (not in `FROM` table list).  It  complains about Vizite.IdMedic is unknown cause table `Vizite` is unknown.

Comment: @kc2018 - you are right. I do not have any idea how to go from here but  you are right.